# getline() method no instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, getline

I am having some problem when trying to do classes for C++. This is my header file.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef MESSAGES__H__
#define MESSAGES__H__

class Message
{
    public:
        Message(std::string recipient, std::string sender);
        void append(std::string text);
        std::string to_string() const;
        void print() const;
    private:
        std::string recipient;
        std::string sender;
        std::string message;
        std::string text_input;
        char* timestamp;
};

#endif
```

And when I run the main method, the getline(cin,) is giving me some error message:

```
int main()
{
    vector <Message*> message_list;
    Message* message1 = new Message("Student1", "Gabriel");
    cout << "Enter message text line, enter . on new line to finish: " << endl;
    while(getline(cin, text_input))
    {
    }
}
```

The getline method is giving me no instance of overloaded function. Also, from the same line, the text_input is showing identifier is undefined. I thought I declared in .h class already?

Thanks in advance.

**Updated portion**

Now all the error has been fixed:

```
vector <Message*> message_list;
Message* message1 = new Message("Saiful", "Gabriel");
cout << "Enter message text line, enter . on new line to finish: " << endl;
while(getline(cin, message1->get_text_input()))
{
    if(message1->get_text_input() == ("."))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        message1->append(message1->get_text_input());
    }
}
```

Inside the while loop, once "." is detected at the beginning of the new line, it supposingly will stop. However, no matter how many times I entered "." at the new line, it just keep prompting. Anybody know why?

Comment: You should copy-paste the error here exactly.

Comment: What you mean by copy-paste the error here? I already wrote it at the last few line. I can't even run the program and what did you expect from the stack trace?

Comment: I mean the compiler error, in other words "is giving me some error message:" <---  that error . verbatim from the compiler

Comment: Try my answer first though, might fix both

Comment: Oh sorry. Because I used to write the error at the bottom

Comment: Nope, I coded it on my own because this is a material given by my teacher. I can do without pointer. But once pointer appear, I will lost

Answer (score 0):

To fix "text_input is showing identifier is undefined"

You need to change

```
 while(getline(cin, text_input))
```

to

```
 while(getline(cin, message1->text_input))
```

Possibly this will fix the first error.

Comment: The error changed to member is inaccessible. Because it's declared as private right? But how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your loop like this:

```
while(getline(cin,&message1->text_input)) 
{

}
```

If I remember correctly, `getline` function looks like this:

```
getline(isstream& stream, string& string)
```

Comment: oh, and you should write getter and setter functions for your members. changing text_input to public will solve your problem but it is ineffective

Comment: No no the code inside while loop I will do it right after I solve the error.

Comment: @Marcel-Is-Hier use formatting and provide a link to make sure you "remember correctly" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: To solve your error, you need to understand what private and public does... Because your text_input member is private it is not accessi8ble outside the class. You should keep it private. Now write a getter and setter function for this member.   Here is a simple getter function              public string TextInput() { return text_input; }                        Using getters and setters with private members promotes your class' encapsulation :) hope this helps.

Comment: I wrote it already but it does not worked out well. while(getline(cin, message1->get_text_input()))
 {
  if(message1->get_text_input() == ("."))
  {
   break;
  }
  else
  {
   message1->append(message1->get_text_input());
  }
 }

Comment: what I am trying to do is once detected "." at the beginning of sentence, it will stop.

Comment: @Marcel-Is-Hier I edited for you - just realised you can't do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It feels as if you are over complicating things. Just use a temporary variable in `getline`. If the input is a "." then break, otherwise append the line to the Message object. As a consequence, you should be able to remove the `text_input` member variable from your Message header file.

```
std::vector<Message*> message_list;
Message* message1 = new Message("Saiful", "Gabriel");
std::cout << "Enter message text line, enter . on new line to finish: " << std::endl;
std::string input = "";
while(getline(std::cin, input))
{
    if(input == ".")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        message1->append(input);
    }
}
```